# Extract labels for generated sequences

Tags: python, list, numpy, slice, sequence

I am trying to create sequences from a labeled dataset of transactions. The labels are 1 for "fraudulent" and 0 for "genuine", and the label column is called: 'is_fraud'.

First, I grouped and all transactions by account number and ordered by time. I was able to extract a set of sequences containing a long sequence for each individual account.

Now I want to create labeled subsequences of some fixed length. However, I don't just want to label the subsequence according to the label of the last transaction in each subsequence - rather I want to label it according to whether there are any "fraudulent" transaction present, then the sequence is labeled with a 1, else labeled as 0.

I want to do this by taking the maximum of each label in the subsequence, however I can not seem to get it to work. This is what I have tried, where `seq_len` is the desired length for the generated subsequences:

```
def generate_seqs(Set_seqs,seq_len):
    Labels = []
    Set_subseqs = [] 
    seq = []
# Create subsequences for each sequence in Set of sequences, using sliding window
    for acc in Set_seqs:
        if len(acc) >= seq_len:
            acc_subseq = [acc[i:i+seq_len] for i in range(len(acc) - seq_len)]
            acc_label = [acc[i:i+seq_len] for i in range(len(acc) - seq_len)]
            acc_label = acc_label['is_fraud']
            acc_label2 = any(acc_label)
            for acc_subseq, acc_label2 in zip(acc_subseq, acc_label2):
                subseq = []
                for observ in acc_subseq:
                    obs = observ.copy()
                    obs.pop('is_fraud') 
                    subseq.append(obs)
                Set_subseqs.append(subseq)
                Labels.append(acc_label2)
    Set_subseqs = np.array(Set_subseqs)
    Labels = np.array(Labels)
    print(Set_subseqs.shape)
    print(Labels.shape)
    return Set_subseqs , Labels
```

I keep getting the error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I am very new to this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your `Set_seqs` a 2D list? Also, are your list objects string type?

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew Yes, the Set_seqs is a 2D list, so if there are 100 account numbers, this is a list containing 100 lists. If I understand correctly, the list objects are individual transactions which consists of the amount, account number and 5 other features. (Hope this answers your question)

Comment: Understood,  how about your `seq_len`? What is the input for that?

Comment: seq_len is just the desired length for the subsequences, for example 20.

Comment: I'm not sure about the mistakes in this code, except the `cc` in the `range` and perhaps try to make sure your `seq_len` is an integer by putting `int()`

Comment: I converted the first `acc_label` into a numpy array and then in the second for loop added `acc_label[:,-1].max()` and that did the trick!